# Using snmpgetnext on a table

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I am writing my own MIB Module containing a table with 2 columns. Using `snmptable` works just fine and retrieves all values of the table with all the rows.
But  with `snmpgetnext` I can only retrieve the first row of the table.

```
snmpgetnext -v2c -c public localhost sensorTable
MY-PERSONAL-MIB::sensorVoltage."1" = STRING: "2.3V"
```

To retrieve the next value I must run:

```
snmpgetnext -v2c -c public localhost sensorVoltage."2"
MY-PERSONAL-MIB::sensorTemperature."1" = "3.2C"
```

Running `snmpgetnext -v2c -c public localhost sensorVoltage."1"` would result in `sensorVoltage."1"` again, the same for `sensorTemperature."1"`.

```
snmpgetnext -v2c -c public localhost sensorTemperature."2"
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpSetSerialNo.0 = INTEGER: 1664041205
```

Also, I ran `snmptable -CB` so the manager only uses `GETNEXT` to retrieve the table values. This works fine as well.
So why can't I retrieve the single values with a simple `snmpgetnext` request? 
As last, snmpget doesn't work at all. I get the following error:

```
snmpget -v2c -c publicl localhost sensorTemperature."1"
MY-PERSONAL-MIB::sensorTemperature.1 = No such Instance currently exists at this OID
```

At last, my code I use for my MIB-Module. I use the handler to read data from a file and create a table struct through it. I tried using snmpgetnext with a table created through the initialization routine resulting in the same problem, so the handler routine shouldn't be the issue here but I still appended it just for completion and well, who knows!

```
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h>
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-includes.h>
#include <net-snmp/agent/net-snmp-agent-includes.h>
#include "sensorTable.h"

#define firstEntryRow 2

netsnmp_table_data_set *table_set;

void
initialize_table_sensorTable(void)
{

netsnmp_ds_set_string(NETSNMP_DS_APPLICATION_ID, NETSNMP_DS_AGENT_X_SOCKET, "tcp:localhost:705");       

const oid sensorTable_oid[] = { 1 ,3 ,6 ,1 ,4 ,1 ,8072 ,1259 ,1 ,1 };

table_set = netsnmp_create_table_data_set("sensorTable");
netsnmp_table_row *row;

table_set->allow_creation = 1;

DEBUGMSGTL(("initialize_table_sensorTable",
            "adding indexes to table sensorTable\n"));
netsnmp_table_dataset_add_index(table_set,
                       ASN_OCTET_STR);

DEBUGMSGTL(("initialize_table_sensorTable",
            "adding column types to table sensorTable\n"));      
netsnmp_table_set_multi_add_default_row(table_set,
                                        COLUMN_SENSORVOLTAGE, ASN_OCTET_STR, 1,
                                        NULL, 0,
                                        COLUMN_SENSORTEMPERATURE, ASN_OCTET_STR, 1,
                                        NULL, 0,
                          0);

netsnmp_register_table_data_set(netsnmp_create_handler_registration("sensorTable", sensorTable_handler,
                                                    sensorTable_oid,
                                                    OID_LENGTH(sensorTable_oid),
                                                    HANDLER_CAN_RWRITE),
                        table_set, NULL);

row = netsnmp_create_table_data_row();
netsnmp_table_row_add_index(row, ASN_OCTET_STR, "1",
                            strlen("1"));   
netsnmp_set_row_column(row, 2, ASN_OCTET_STR,
                       "5.9V", strlen("5.9V"));
netsnmp_set_row_column(row, 3, ASN_OCTET_STR,
                       "21.5C", strlen("21.5C"));
netsnmp_table_dataset_add_row(table_set, row);


}


void
init_sensorTable(void)
{
    initialize_table_sensorTable();
}

int
sensorTable_handler(
netsnmp_mib_handler               *handler,
netsnmp_handler_registration      *reginfo,
netsnmp_agent_request_info        *reqinfo,
netsnmp_request_info              *requests) {

netsnmp_table_row *row, *tempRow;

if( table_set != NULL )
{

    for ( tempRow = table_set->table->first_row; 
          tempRow; tempRow = tempRow->next )
    {
        row = netsnmp_table_data_set_get_first_row(table_set);
        netsnmp_table_dataset_remove_row(table_set, row);
    } 
}

/* Start reading "input.txt */
char sensorValues[32];
char *singleValue;
FILE *f = fopen("/home/supra/Desktop/input.txt", "r");

/* check if the file was found */
if( f == NULL ) {
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}

/* check if the file is empty */
if ( fgets( sensorValues, sizeof(sensorValues), f) == NULL )
{
    printf("Warning: File is empty!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}   

/* if the file is not empty, create a row and start
 * breaking the string into words. Fill the row with the words
 * and add it to the table. */
do
{
    int rowEntries = firstEntryRow;
    singleValue = strtok( sensorValues, " ");
    row = netsnmp_create_table_data_row();
    netsnmp_table_row_add_index(row, ASN_OCTET_STR, singleValue, strlen(singleValue) );     
    singleValue = strtok( NULL, " ");

    /* Fill the row with values */
    while(singleValue != NULL)
    {
        netsnmp_set_row_column(row, rowEntries, ASN_OCTET_STR, singleValue, strlen(singleValue) );
        rowEntries++;
        singleValue = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    netsnmp_table_dataset_add_row(table_set, row);

} while( fgets( sensorValues, sizeof(sensorValues), f) != NULL);
fclose(f);

return SNMP_ERR_NOERROR;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding :

> So why can't I retrieve the single values with a simple snmpgetnext request?

Quoting `man snmpgetnext`

> DESCRIPTION
>          snmpget is an SNMP application that uses the SNMP GETNEXT request to query for information on a network entity.  One or more
>   object identifiers (OIDs) may
>          be given as arguments on the command line.  Each variable name is given in the format specified in variables(5).  For each one, the
>   variable that is lexicographically "next" in the remote entity's MIB will be returned. For example:
>
> snmpgetnext -c public zeus interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifType.1
>
> will retrieve the variable 
>   interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifType.2

In other words its job is to get one thing back.

If you want to use it to get a full table, you need to invoke it multiple times. Quoting man page for `snmptable` :

> snmptable  is  an  SNMP application that repeatedly uses the SNMP GETNEXT or GETBULK requests to query for information on a network entity.

Comment: I understood that so far. Problem is that if I chain `snmpgetnext` by hand I do not get the entrys as I do by just using `snmptable`. All entries beyond the first get skipped and I jump over to the next column. I may have a bug though in my code I just realized, so maybe fixing it will help!